# In Tkinter is it possible to get the accelerator value of a command of a menu

Tags: python, tkinter, menu

So for example lets say we have the code:

```
def startinvoke():  
 pass  

menubar = tk.Menu(window)  
controlsMenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=1)  
controlsMenu.add_command(label="Start", underline=0, accelerator="Command-.", command=startinvoke())  
window.bind(f"<{Value of the start command's accelerator}>", lambda event: startinvoke())
```

What I'm trying to do here is to get the value of Start's accelerator and insert it into the binding (and/or be able to edit it later). How is this possible in Tkinter?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.entrycget()` as below:

```py
window.bind(f"<{controlsMenu.entrycget('Start', 'accelerator')}>", lambda e: startinvoke())
```